How can I get a docker compose container's replica number from inside it, without special tools?
I have a docker compose project where one of the services launches several replicas using the replicas directive.  The replicas have automatically enumerated names, which also serve as hostnames.  Note, this different to container id.
I want to find out what the replica number of a container is from inside itself, without installing special tools (like dig, etc), or running runtime commands with exec.  I'm okay with passing in an environment variable, but I don't know how to access that number in order to make it an environment variable.
The solutions I've seen either involve bloating the container with tools, confuse the concept of the id with the name, or suggest stuff like cat'ing /proc/self/cgroup, which just doesn't work for me.

"confuse the concept of the id with the name" ... The developers themselves are the ones suggesting that you derive the ID from the name: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9153
